# Could not instantiate bean class [com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.ajax.DatatablesCriterias]: No default constructor found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0, dandelion

Do you know why I am getting this error?

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [enemr] in context with path [/enemr] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.ajax.DatatablesCriterias]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.ajax.DatatablesCriterias.<init>()] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.ajax.DatatablesCriterias.<init>()
```

I changed my controller from this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<Results> findAllForDataTables(HttpServletRequest request) {

        DatatablesCriterias dataTableCriterias = DatatablesCriterias.getFromRequest(request);
        DataSet<Results> results = this.resultsServiceimpl.findResultsWithDatatablesCriterias(dataTableCriterias);
        return DatatablesResponse.build(results, dataTableCriterias);
    }
```

to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody 
    DatatablesResponse<Results> findAllForDataTables(@DatatablesParams DatatablesCriterias criterias) {

        DataSet<Results> results = this.resultsServiceimpl.findResultsWithDatatablesCriterias(criterias);
        return DatatablesResponse.build(results, criterias);
    }
```

and suddenly stop working

any help highly appreciated.

I am using spring 3.2 and dandelion datatables 1.1.0

Comment: The exception is as clear as it can be: there's no default constructor for the DatatablesCriterias class, and the bean factory requires one.  You shouldn't be passing that as a parameter.

Comment: I just followed this sample [here](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables-samples/blob/master/datatables-jsp-ajax/src/main/java/com/github/dandelion/datatables/web/ajax/AjaxController.java)

Comment: Believe the JVM, not the sample.  Who creates criteria?

Comment: It is a project created by dandelion. It is based on JQuery Datatables. See their websites [here](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/)

Comment: I think the first controller is correct; the JVM agrees with me.  Why the change?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.1.0/docs/html/#starting-from-spring-3-1) I can use the spring extra module to do the above

Answer (score 1):

When you changed your controller to use `DatatablesParams` annotation you need to enable a resolver which will instantiate `DatatablesCriterias` object. Because spring 3.2 is in use, `DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgumentResolver` need to be enabled:

through xml:

```
     <!-- Add support for @DatatablesParams annotations in controller's methods -->
   <mvc:annotation-driven>
      <mvc:argument-resolvers>
         <bean class="com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.spring3.ajax.DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgumentResolver" />
      </mvc:argument-resolvers>
   </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

or java config:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
         argumentResolvers.add(new DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgumentResolver());
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you - This helped me!